# Replace Same values in a column if value in next row is same

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010, formula

I have values in column a, please give me formula to get values in column b

```
COLUMN "a"
----------
NNII
NNII
NNII
NKJE
NNII
BLFL
BLFL
NKD#54
NKD#54
NKD#54
NKD#54
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI
LWEI

COLUMN "b"
----------
NNII
0
0
NKJE
NNII
BLFL
0
NKD#54
0
0
0
LWEI
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Uh, what?  Could you please clear this up a bit?

Comment: IF MY A6=A7=A8=A9 THEN I NEED B6=A6, THEN B7=0, B8=0, B9=0

Answer (score 0):

I think I udnerstand what you want.  The forumula is:

```
=IF(a6=b6,a6)
```

Will return the value of a6 if b6 is the same.  Or else it returns FALSE.

```
a   b   c
NII NII NII
NII 0   FALSE
```

Comment: No if my a6=a7=a8=a9, then my b6=a6, b7=0, b8=0, b9=0 etc